# implementing admob SmartBanner in ListView

Tags: java, android, admob

Lately I integrated an AdMob Banner into my ListView. Now I would like to replace that Banner by a smart-banner, because it looks much better.
The normal banner is implemented like explained in this tutorial:
[Tutorial](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.de/2012/03/embedding-admob-ads-within-listview-on.html)

My problem with SmartBanner is, that i can't get the Height of it, before it is loaded, like it is possible with normal banner: `int height = Math.round(AdSize.BANNER.getHeight() * density);`

My Question: How can I implement a SmartBanner properly into a ListView?
I already experimented with a fixed hight of 90px, but that is not the best solution, because some Ads are much smaller and it results in unused space around the ad.